# Continue code if $model->save() fails

Tags: php, laravel, exception, namespaces, laravel-5

How can I make sure the PHP code continue to run even if the $model->save() fails?

I have a unique index on the url column, so my code will fail on purpose sometimes, but I want to make sure the code doesn't stop because of that.

```
$url = new \App\Url;
$url->url = 'http://www.example.com';
$url->save();
```

I tried try catch like this:

```
$url = new \App\Url;
$url->url = 'http://www.example.com';
try {
    $url->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //       
}
```

But it still throws a MySQL error and the code stops.

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 614:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'http://www.example.com' for key 'url_index' (SQL: insert into `urls` (`url`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (http://www.example.com, 2015-02-15 09:25:40, 2015-02-15 09:25:40))
```

Comment: What exactly exception is thrown by Laravel when you use this code ?

Comment: I just edited the post to include the error message. It throws an error about duplicate entry in the database, which is reasonable, because it is duplicate. But I just want to ignore the error and continue running my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think might be a problem with namespace here, try something like this:

```
$url = new \App\Url;
$url->url = 'http://www.example.com';
try {
    $url->save();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //       
}
```